# DataSpell Markdown formatting

Tags: dataspell

Just started using JetBrains DataSpell and I have noticed formatting Markdown cell is not as elegant as with conventional Jupyter Notebook. Text rendered is annoying. Do I need a some plugins? Any insights?

Comment: I may only suggest to check the DataSpell Issue Tracker for the related tickets -- you may find some hints in one of them. If nothing -- consider making a ticket with examples: a text (markdown content) to play with and screenshots of how it is rendered in DataSpell and another tool (i.e. Jupyter Notebook). https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DS?q=markdown